# Interconnected variables in snakemake

Tags: snakemake

Let's say I have sample `SAMPLE_A`, divided into two files `SAMPLE_A_1, SAMPLE_A_2` and associated to barcodes `AATT, TTAA`,  and `SAMPLE_B`associated to barcodes `CCGG, GGCC, GCGC`, divided in 4 files `SAMPLE_B_1...SAMPLE_B_4`.

I can create `getSampleNames()` to get `[SAMPLE_A,SAMPLE_A,SAMPLE_B,SAMPLE_B,SAMPLE_B,SAMPLE_B]` and `[1,2,1,2,3,4]` and then zip them to get the combination `{sample}_{id}`. And then I can do the same thing for the barcodes: `[SAMPLE_A,SAMPLE_A,SAMPLE_B,SAMPLE_B,SAMPLE_B]` and `[AATT, TTAA,CCGG, GGCC, GCGC]`.

```
SAMPLES_ID,IDs = getSampleNames()
SAMPLES_BC,BCs = getBCs(set(SAMPLES_ID))

rule refine:
input:
    '{sample}/demultiplex/{sample}_{id}.demultiplex.bam'
output:
    bam = '{sample}/polyA_trimming/{sample}_{id}.fltnc.bam',
shell:
    "isoseq3 refine {input} "


rule split:
input:
    expand('{sample}/polyA_trimming/{sample}_{id}.fltnc.bam', zip, sample = SAMPLES_ID, id = IDs),
output:
    expand("{sample}/cells/{barcode}_{sample}/fltnc.bam", zip, sample = SAMPLES_BC, barcode = BCs),
shell:
    "python {params.script_dir}/split_cells_bam.py"


rule dedup_split:
input:
    "{sample}/cells/{barcode}_{sample}/fltnc.bam"
output:
    bam = "{sample}/cells/{barcode}_{sample}/dedup/dedup.bam",
shell:
    "isoseq3 dedup {input} {output.bam} "

rule merge:
input:
    expand("{sample}/cells/{barcode}_{sample}/dedup/dedup.bam",
        zip, sample = SAMPLES_BC, barcode = BCs),
```

How can I prevent the rule split to be a bottleneck in my pipeline? For now it waits for the refine rule to be done for all samples while it's not necessary, every sample should run independently, but I can't because the set of barcodes is different for each sample. Is there a way to have something like

`expand("{sample}/cells/{barcode}_{sample}/fltnc.bam", zip, sample = SAMPLES_BC, barcode = BCs[SAMPLES_BC])`, where each `{sample}` of `SAMPLES_BC` is a key in `BCs` dictionary ? And same for `IDs`? I know I can use functions, but then I'm not sure how to propagate the `{barcode}` through the rules

Comment: To clarify, given SAMPLE_A and barcode AATT as output from split, what inputs should it have?  Or is it that you can do all of SAMPLE_A together?

Comment: For rule split, input are SAMPLE_A_1.fltnc.bam and SAMPLE_A_2.fltnc.bam (so all of SAMPLE_A together), and output are cells/AATT_SAMPLE_A/fltnc.bam and cells/TTAA_SAMPLE_A/fltnc.bam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to use dictionaries through functions, which solved my problem!

The major default of this solution is that you have to create a dummy file as output of the split rule, instead of checking if each '{sample}/cells/{barcode}_{sample}/fltnc.bam' file is created, so I am still looking for something more elegant...

```
IDs = getSampleNames() #{SAMPLE_A:[1,2], SAMPLE_B:[1,2,3,4]}
SAMPLES = list(IDs.keys()) 
BCs = getBCs(SAMPLES) #{SAMPLE_A:[AATT, TTAA], SAMPLE_B:[CCGG,GGCC,GCGC]}
    
# function linking IDs and SAMPLE
def sample2ids(wildcards):
    return expand('{{sample}}/polyA_trimming/{{sample}}_{id}.fltnc.bam', 
               id = IDs[wildcards.sample])

# function linking BCs and SAMPLE
def sample2ids(wildcards):
    return expand('{{sample}}/cells/{barcode}_{{sample}}/dedup/dedup.bam',
               barcode = BCs[wildcards.sample])

rule refine:
input:
    '{sample}/demultiplex/{sample}_{id}.demultiplex.bam'
output:
    bam = '{sample}/polyA_trimming/{sample}_{id}.fltnc.bam',

rule split:
input:
    sample2ids
output:
    # cannot use a function here, so I create a dummy file to pipe
    'dummy_file.txt'

rule dedup_split:
input:
    'dummy_file.txt'
output:
    bam = "{sample}/cells/{barcode}_{sample}/dedup/dedup.bam",


rule merge:
input:
    sample2bc
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, there are a few routes to take which would involve changing your data structure holding the samples, barcodes, and ids.  For now, you can just create a rule per sample:

```
for sample in set(SAMPLES_ID):  # get uniq samples
    # get ids and barcodes for this sample
    ids = [tup[1] for tup in zip(SAMPLES_ID, IDs) if tup[0] == sample]
    bcs = [tup[1] for tup in zip(SAMPLES_BC, BCs) if tup[0] == sample]

    rule:
        name: f'{sample}_split'
        input:
            expand('{sample}/polyA_trimming/{sample}_{id}.fltnc.bam', 
                   sample = sample, id = ids),
        output:
            expand("{sample}/cells/{barcode}_{sample}/fltnc.bam", 
                   sample = sample, barcode = bcs),
        shell:
            "python {params.script_dir}/split_cells_bam.py"
```

You don't need zip in the expand since the ids and bcs are for the single sample.  I don't think this is the best way in general, but will be easiest for your current workflow.

Just noticing your shell command, how are you passing the input/output to your script?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, but I was never able to use a rule inside the for loop, it would just ignore the for and take the same set of ids and bcs for each sample no matter what. I found a way to do what I wanted using functions though, I'll post the answer (no worries about the shell command, I just oversimplified my example)